# How to relocate SVN Repo in HUDSON?

Tags: svn, hudson

My **HUDSON** builds are using SVN repository to checkout the code. Currently we were using `http` protocol to access the SVN repo, but now we have moved to `https`. Any idea, how shall I relocate the SVN repo location in Hudson configuration to avoid **"Fresh Checkout"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log into the machine which is hosting the workspaces then you can run an [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) to change the source url. Once that is done and before you run any builds change the locations to match in hudson.